# Which NoSQL database suited to store different type of orders?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

I work for a financial organization where user can place 20 different type of investment requets like following.

lumpsum investment
setting up a regular saving plan
switch order.
Etc...

Each order has specific attributes and different from each other.

Traditionally I have been using relational database for 5 years but I think this what I don't want as I have to have a common schema which at times difficult to manage .

Apart from flexible storage (document style) I have requirements to Search all the orders based on certain attributes like customer name or order type.

Few NFRs

I need strong consistency
Volumes per day are limited so basically scaling is not a big problem.

Can someone suggest which NoSQL will meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons NoSQL databases gained popularity was because of the need to scale effectively. If your primary requirement is to not manage a "common schema" , I am not sure if NoSQL is the best option for you.

Any way, with the requirements you have, you might want to look at CouchDB which is a document based NoSQL database that has document-level ACID semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be a good read. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-Cassandra-and-MongoDB . The question might not be stack overflow material that much. There is just so much other info one would need to make a decision.

Basically if your access pattern is not clear right away cassandra might not be the best choice. But once you know how you access your data etc. you might port to cassandra.

There are a lot of success stories on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If scaling is NOT the problem, I suggest you just to use PostgreSQL and store all specific attributes in one column in JSON format. Postgres have a good performance for storing and indexing such kind of data.